# Глобальная переменная Angular2

Tags: angular2, typescript

Имеется несколько компонентов. Корневой, и не сколько страниц. Переход на другую страницу происходит с помощью

```
this.navCtrl.push(CityPage);
```

Мне необходимо с каждой страницы, запоминать выбранный элемент. Как можно для этого создать глобальную переменную?

У меня только идеи, либо добавлять все в Локальное хранилище. Или передавать в каждый компонент новые данные так

```
this.navCtrl.push(CityPage, params[]);
```

Нормальные ли это решения? И как можно это реализовать через глобальную переменную

Comment: Это можно сделать через сервис

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1 - задекларировать переменную например в app.module `declare  var params:any = [];`, но это не сильно классно.

Вариант 2 - создать как написал Александр создать сервис-модель, сделать её `@Injectable` поместить в `providers` модуля и дополнять в компонентах.

Всё это выглядит приблизительно так:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()

    export class ParamsModel {
        private params:any = [];

        constructor() {}

        public setParams(param) {
            this.params.push(param);
        }

        public getParams() {
            return this.params;
        }
    }
```

app.module

```
    import {ParamsModel} from "PATH/TO/FOLDER";
    ...
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ....
      ],
      declarations: [
        ...
      ],
      providers: [
        ParamsModel
      ],
       ...
    })
```

Ну а самой компоненте ...

```
        ...
    export class YourComponent{

        constructor(private paramsModel:ParamsModel) {
            console.log(paramsModel.getParams());
        }


    }
```

Comment: а *CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA* зачем?

Comment: @Grundy ой, да прошу прощения,  это из проекта не убрал